# Using Delayed Job on getting geocords with gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, gmaps4rails

I am looking at using the gem [google maps for rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) but cant see how I can use delayed_job to get the cords after creating a new record.

Has anyone come across this gem before with using delayed_job

Hope someone can advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I'm not sure how much you know about Delayed Job, so I'll start there.

Delayed job can utilize any class that responds to '#perform', so the first thing you need is a class for getting the coordinates and storing them in your model.

```
class GoogleMapsCoordinateService

  def perform(record)
    coords = Gmaps4rails.geocode(record.address) #This is the method that will actually return a hash of coordinates for each match it finds.

    record.update_attributes(:lattitude => coords[0][:lat], :longitude => coords[0][:lng])
  end
end
```

Then you just need to enqueue that job in an after_create hook in the model

```
class INSERTYOURMODELNAMEHERE < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :get_coordinates

  def get_coordinates
    Delayed::Job.enqueue GoogleMapsCoordinateService.new(self)
  end
end
```

So that way, after each record is created, you will queue up the grabbing of the coordinates in the background while keeping your response time snappy.

Comment: I had to put the variable into a Struct to get this working: 'class GoogleMapsCoordinateService < Struct.new(:record)'